# MYSQL filtering using AS name of column

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query (minimal version) to filter some data from a table

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t.name AS tname, 
CASE WHEN (t.task_group != -1) THEN (SELECT p.keyid FROM proyects AS p, task_groups AS tg WHERE tg.keyid = t.task_group AND tg.proyect = p.keyid) ELSE -1 END AS pkeyid 
FROM tasks AS t, task_users AS tu 
WHERE (t.status = '0' OR t.status = '1' OR t.status = '3') AND (t.keyid = tu.task) AND ((tu.worker = 5));
```

The query works perfectly. But now I want to filter some of the rows by doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t.name AS tname, 
CASE WHEN (t.task_group != -1) THEN (SELECT p.keyid FROM proyects AS p, task_groups AS tg WHERE tg.keyid = t.task_group AND tg.proyect = p.keyid) ELSE -1 END AS pkeyid 
FROM tasks AS t, task_users AS tu 
WHERE (t.status = '0' OR t.status = '1' OR t.status = '3') AND (t.keyid = tu.task) AND ((tu.worker = 5)) AND ((pkeyid = 7) OR (pkeyid = 8) OR (pkeyid = 16))
```

I get the syntax error "Unknown column 'pkeyid' in 'where clause'"

I can understand why this is happening (pkeyid is not a column in any of the tables in the from clause). Is there a simple way around this? Or do I have to rewrite the entire query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the alias name in the where clause, you need to use having clause if you want that to be used in the filtering something as

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t.name AS tname, 
CASE WHEN (t.task_group != -1) THEN (SELECT p.keyid FROM proyects AS p, task_groups AS tg WHERE tg.keyid = t.task_group AND tg.proyect = p.keyid) ELSE -1 END AS pkeyid 
FROM tasks AS t, task_users AS tu 
WHERE 
(t.status = '0' OR t.status = '1' OR t.status = '3') 
AND t.keyid = tu.task 
AND tu.worker = 5
having
pkeyid = 7 or pkeyid = 8 or pkeyid = 16
```